# How can I Enable Google Earth 3D features in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, 3d, google

I want to ask if there is any plugin or any other way where I can use Google Earth features in QGIS. When I'm saying Google Earth features I mean to be able to see roads, towns, etc and to be able to use the 3D option (Street view tool) I have already installed the OpenLayers Plugin but I did not find something to do it.

Comment: Do you specifically want to see roads and towns from google's servers?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know there is no way to use Google Street View in QGIS.

QGIS without Globe does not offer 3D capabilities. Globe is a work in progress and currently does not work on Windows according to Sourcepole (http://sourcepole.ch/the-state-of-qgis-globe).

Answer (score 1):

Street view is a series of equirectangular still images with geographic reference data, there is nothing to import there that would be usable in QGIS, even if it were possible.

As for the 3D data contained within Google Earth, manipulation, or even data access outside of a Google approved platform is against their terms of service, and not allowed.  Also, QGIS does not [currently] have a 3D viewer to view the data, even if it were allowed.